# Schematron & Xpath, testing for valid set of sub-elements and attributes

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, schematron

Since XSD doesn't cover my needs, i'm now evaluating Schematron. testing for other than allowed elements seems impossible.
I need to validate elements where `@type="colorSet"`.. 
Next tests are most important for me:

`any other than this set of attributes` and

`any other than this set of optional elements`

secondly how to `check if values are alphanumerical or digits`

Fyi, the valid XML options are;

```
<defaultBgColor type="colorSet" r="255" g="255" b="255"/>
<defaultBgColor type="colorSet" r="255" g="255" b="255" a="100"/>
<paint type="colorSet">
  <index>140</index>
</paint>
<paint type="colorSet">
  <name>blue</name>
</paint>
```

I want to test;

- 'R','G','B' must be present
- 'A' is optional , any other attribute not allowed
- only 'index' or 'name' sub-elements allowed

This is the experpt of where i'm stuck;

```
    <!-- Don't know how to do the second assert? -->
    <rule context="//*[@type='colorSet' and count(child::*) = 0]">
      <assert test="@r and @g and @b"           >One of R G B missing</assert>
      <assert test="any other than @r,@g,@b,@a" >Invalid attribute   </assert>
    </rule>

    <!-- is a test like isNumber possible? -->
    <assert test="isNumber( text() )">Index is not a number</assert>

    <!-- is a test like isAlpha possible? -->
    <assert test="isAlpha( substring(text(),1) )">Invalid name</assert>

    <!-- How to assert "any other than valid (optional) elements" -->
```

Any comment or hint is welcome!

Comment: I would say that XML Schema can validate those constraints. Is there another reason why XML schema does not cover your needs?

Comment: Well.. i think the main thing i need & what XML Schema doesn't support. Like <XYZ type="color">  XYZ may be any element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
<assert test="count(@*) > count(@r|@g|@b|@a)" >Invalid attribute   </assert> 

<assert test="number(.) = number(.)">Index is not a number</assert> 

<!-- It depends on what you mean: "does it start with no digit" -->
<assert test="not(contains('0123456789',substring(.,1,1)))"
       >Invalid name</assert>
```

Comment: Amazing what a bit of creativity can do :)